# How to select default country on table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I build an app which require phone verification. I can change country code when I click button. By default, the selected country must be country with "60" (for example). It should work like this: click button - appear country list, and the default country should have checkmark. Then if I click another country, the latest selected country should have checkmark if I click the button. But what happen is, when the callingCode = "60" (by default), it doesn't get through the codes after that (let i =..). That code (let i =..) will get through only if the callingCode = vc.country.calling_code. Is anyone know what is the best way to do this?

```
func selectDefaultCountry(countries: [Countries]) {
    var callingCode = ""

    if vc.country.calling_code != ""  {
        callingCode = vc.country.calling_code
    }
    else {
        callingCode = "60"
    }

    if let i = countries.firstIndex(where: {$0.calling_code == callingCode}) {

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)

        vc.changeCountryTV.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
        // Green checkmark
        vc.changeCountryTV.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        vc.changeCountryTV.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.tintColor = Constants.Colors.greenColor
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to check in `cellForRow` if the model at that particular cell's callingCode matched your selected callingCode and update the checkmark accordingly as well. So after selection all you should be doing is reloading that particular row instead of manually updating the UI and `cellForRow` will handle the rest

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to compare selected country in `cellForRowAt indexPath` method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Your code for initialize UITableView cell
    let country = countries[indexPath.row]
    if(vc.country.calling_code == country.calling_code)
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    else
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your country object in below manner

```
struct CountryModel:Decodable{
    var countries:[Country]?
}

struct Country:Decodable {
    var name:String?
    var isSelected:Bool?
}
```

In You SelectDefaultCountry function set isSelected to True and if the user tries to change by clicking on the country button, First change all isSelected to false and make true for one selected.  This should make it easier for you to manage.